# How to submit form on change of dropdown list?

Tags: html, jsp

I am creating a page in JSP where I have a dropdown list and once the user selects a value he has to click on the go button and then the value is sent to the Servlet.

```
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="GO" value="Go"/>
```

How do I make it so that it does it on change? E.g. when the user selects John all his details are retrived from the DB and displayed. I want the system to do it without having to click the go button.

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onchange` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead. Please _never_ suggest or encourage these attributes. The last browser that still needs them reached end of life nearly two decades ago. It’s `document.getElementById("yourSelect").addEventListener("change", ({ target }) => target.form.submit());`.

Comment: How TF is that more intuitive...

Answer (score 857, accepted):

Just ask assistance of JavaScript.

```
<select onchange="this.form.submit()">
    ...
</select>
```

#### See also:

- [HTML dog - JavaScript tutorial](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/htmlintermediate/javascript/)

Comment: A lot of users block javascript, is there a way to do this without javascript?

Comment: @deweydb: Nope. I would otherwise have answered it :) Just show a `<noscript>` banner that site's experience is better if JS is enabled. A completely different alternative is to use `<ul><li><input type="submit">` and throw in a load of CSS to make it look like a true dropdown list. But then there's no means of a `<select>` anymore.

Comment: @deweydb "A lot of users block javascript…" Citation? I've honestly never come across a user that blocks javascript - I've started to believe that these users are a myth. It would prevent them from using half of the internet, for one thing; and anyone savvy enough to block script is probably aware of how innocuous and ubiquitous it is.

Comment: @BalusC please add this for people that are worried about users not having javascript enabled  `<noscript>This form requires that you have javascript enabled to work properly please enable javascript in your browser.</noscript>`  also  @NathanHornby if you really want a citation why dont you go to a public library most public library's block javascript for security reasons as well as some schools too so don't try to pass it off as a myth it has and is being done mainly for security reasons to keep the integrity of computers as some javascript is malicious code...

Comment: @Kamijou: This is already covered in my 1st comment, along with a second alternative.

Comment: @BalusC ah sorry bout that

Comment: Hi, just came across your answer, is there a way to tell JS to ignore a default (selected) option? I.e. only submit if the option doesn't match the default one (which would be something like "Choose Action")? Thanks!

Comment: Beware using id="submit" for submit buttons in the form. This will cause TypeError - not a function! :)

Comment: @MichalVrchota only if you use `onchange="submit()"` in a certain non-standards-compliant webbrowser developed by some team in Redmond. The answer in its current form is in a different syntax.

Comment: @deweydb It's simple. Just put a `submit` button in `<noscript>` tags. It will only show if the users use noscript. Users who have JS enabled can simple select the element, and users with noscript will just click the submit button. :)

Comment: How can I put specific action in this?

Comment: @huykon225 `if (oldValue != newValue) specificAction()`

Comment: @NathanHornby I block javascript using NoScript extension for Firefox. Then, when website is broken (almost all of them are) I only enable those scripts that bring it back to functional state, and leave various trackers turned off. Basically, I manually opt-in to use javascript on internet.

Comment: This seems to submit a random form on the page instead of the containing form of the select.

Comment: @Arrow_Raider: that may happen when you're nesting forms, which is illegal in HTML.

Answer (score 115):

Simple JavaScript will do -

```
<form action="myservlet.do" method="POST">
    <select name="myselect" id="myselect" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Here is a link for a good [javascript tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript).

Comment: Thanks!, Above one is worked for MVC too  @using (Html.BeginForm("Actioname", "controllername", FormMethod.Post))   <select name="myselect" id="myselect" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
    </select>

Answer (score 22):

other than using `this.form.submit()` you also can submiting by id or name.
example i have form like this : `<form action="" name="PostName" id="PostID">`

1. By Name : `<select onchange="PostName.submit()">`
2. By Id : `<select onchange="PostID.submit()">`

Comment: No JavaScript needed!

Comment: I know, that's what I meant by my comment.  I was trying to give you some props.  :-)

Comment: Wait, is that seriously not JavaScript?

Comment: Anything written inside on* attributes is interpretted as Javascript. So PostName.submit() is javascript.

Comment: The parentheses indicate we're dealing with a "function". HTML is a declarative and not an imperative language, so it doesn't have the concept of a function so submit() is JavaScript.
Your other cue would be when you write an <input> tag for example, you are telling the browser *what exists there*. When you write PostName.submit() you are telling the browser *what to do* under a certain condition. That's roughly the difference between declarative and imperative languages.

Comment: for me it is showing the name of the form is not defined, with this way of solution

Answer (score 18):

To those in the answer above. It's definitely JavaScript. It's just inline.

BTW the jQuery equivalent if you want to apply to all selects:

```js
$('form select').on('change', function(){
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: Simpler methods exist.  Keep it simple.