# How to use javascript to POST PHP variable from HTML select options onchange?

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

I have a simple dropdown menu and I would like to reload the page in order to submit a value via PHP $_POST WITHOUT clicking a submit button. Could I do this with javascript? if so, how?

Comment: So when do you want the post to be triggered? On change of the dropdown?

Comment: Already answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231157/how-to-submit-form-on-change-of-dropdown-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want something along the lines of this…

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="POST">
    <select id="mySelect" name="mySelect" onchange="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">
        <option value="optionOne">Option One</option>
        <option value="optionTwo">Option Two</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

AJAX is the answer. If you have jQuery in your page, use something like:

```
$("#mySelectBox").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val(); //here you have the value of the selected option

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "myscript.php",
        data: { value : selected } //this value will be accessible in your script via $_POST["value"]
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

If you REALLY want to reload the page, although this seems a bit ugly since it might be uncomfortable for the user to select something in a dropdown list and having the page reloaded, jQuery can also make it very easy to do:

```
$("#mySelectBox").change(function() {
    $("#myForm").submit();
}
```

Comment: OP says "I would like to reload the page".  While what you have is certainly more of the "modern" way to do it (and what I would suggest if starting from scratch), the OP may have a reason for wanting the reload.

Comment: Actually I'm going to try to use this instead. I'm not very familiar with javascript. Where do i place this jquery script in my webpage?

Comment: I usually open a <script> tag in the end of my document's body element and put small scripts like these there. But be aware that this is jQuery so you need to import this library in your page. For this, put the following inside your head element: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Also, note that I assumed that your form id is "myForm" and your select box's id is "mySelectBox" ;)

Answer (score 3):

made a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/9p7nc/

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
<select name="value" id="value" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
    <option value="green">green</option>
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use jQuery you could do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
   $('#yourSelect').change(function(){
      $('#hiddenSubmitButton').click();
   })
});

</script>
```

Comment: Why would you do this instead of just calling the form's `submit()` function directly?