# remove submit button with value , create onchange form

Tags: javascript, forms

I need an onchange select to submit value 1 to a name. I sow some questions but I couldn't do it. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231157/how-to-submit-form-on-change-of-dropdown-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to force the form to submit the value of 1 then I'd create a simple function that sets an input in the form to 1 (possibly hidden) and then submit it as per the link you provided.