# JavaScript/HTML website: detect option selected in select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create a google web map using google maps v3, and I want to include a function whereby when the user selects a time (e.g. 6AM) in a select option (dropdown list), the markers fitting this condition will appear. However, when I try this, google chrome's console only detects the default selected option and doesn't change the value as selected accordingly. (you can say it doesn't do a postback I suppose?) I looked around and found a solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231157/how-to-submit-form-on-change-of-dropdown-list), and added the codes in accordingly

```
 <select id="ddlTime" onchange="this.form.submit()"> ...
```

but this is what was returned in my console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null

Comment: Could you please include the full HTML form code?

Answer (score 1):

`this` does not reference the `select` when used in that manner. As you've tagged jQuery, here's how to do it:

```
$('#ddlTime').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

If you would prefer to stick with the `onchange` attribute (which I would advise against, as they are outdated, ugly and bad for separation of concerns) then you could access the `forms` collection of the `window`:

```
<select id="ddlTime" onchange="forms[0].submit()">
</select>
```

The above is obviously assuming that the form you want to submit is the first one in the DOM.