# How to submit value in <select><option> without submit button.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

This is my code:

```html
<form action="?sort=SELECTEDVALUEHERE" method="GET">
<select>
<option value="1">Option 1 </option>
<option value="2">Option 2 </option>
<option value="3">Option 3 </option>
<option value="4">Option 4 </option>
<option value="5">Option 5 </option>
</select>
</form>
```

This is what i want:

If someone click on option 1, it will submit the form. I do not want to add a submit button

this one:

```
<input type=submit />
```

Comment: Call `form.submit()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231157/how-to-submit-form-on-change-of-dropdown-list

Comment: You should probably add an empty option at the beginning. Otherwise, option 1 will be selected by default, and clicking it won't change the selection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call .submit() in `<select>`:

```
<select onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

Comment: i want to send this url `?page='.$page.'&option=SelectedOptionHere`

Where to write it?

Comment: This is where your data will be sent to: `action="?sort=SELECTEDVALUEHERE"`

Comment: Yeah, i know, but i want to change it to the url, which i told u...if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Set `id` attribute for `form` element, and trigger `submit` event when `select` change event occurs.

```
$("select").change(function(){
     $("form").submit();
}
```

Comment: i want to send this url `?page='.$page.'&option=SelectedOptionHere`

Where to write it?

Comment: set your `select` element with `"name"="option"` attribute, then add a `<input name="page" type="hidden" value="$page."/>` into form...then add my js code above and it will submit data as you expected