# How to send values with <select> <option> form using this.form.submit()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

This is my code:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" value=" <?php echo $category1; ?> ">
    <input type="hidden" value=" <?php echo $category2; ?> ">
    <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="sortby">
       <option value="popularity">Popularity</option>
       <option value="release_dateo" >Release Date: Oldest</option>
       <option value="vote_count" >Number Of Votes</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

I am using this form because, i want to submit the form without submit button.

What this code do:

It submits the `<option>` value, if someone click on an option.

What I want it to do:

If someone click on `<option>`, if sends option value + the hidden values.

The url is something like this before submitting the form:

```
index.php?category1=abc&category2=xyz&sortby=selectedoptionvaluehere
```

Comment: what you want exactly??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to submit form on change of dropdown list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231157/how-to-submit-form-on-change-of-dropdown-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing `name` attribute at hidden input's to be sent..

```
<input type="hidden" name="category1" value=" <?php echo $category1; ?> ">
<input type="hidden" name="category2" value=" <?php echo $category2; ?> ">
```