# PHP: Trying to Filter Database information in a table using a combo-box

Tags: php, html, database, web

So I am trying to sort information based the selected item in the combo box. I am familiar with parts of PHP but still learning.

I was able to fill the combo box with the 'Brand_Name' Column information from my DB.

This is my current output:
[image]

It is not filtering though, it is just listing all items in the DB

See code below:

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$databaseName = "Clients";
$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
$queryDropdown = "SELECT * FROM `Brands` WHERE 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $queryDropdown);
$queryGrid = "SELECT * FROM `Brands` ";
$SearchResult = mysqli_query($connect, $queryGrid);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PokerPass</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/Main.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/ComboBox.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/TableGrid.css">
</head>
<body >
    <div id="Container" class="Container">
        <div id="Header" class="Header">

        </div>
        <div id="Body" class="Body">
            <div name="start" id="Filter_Bar" class="Filter_Bar">
                <select class="soflow" id="soflow" Size="1">
                  <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):; ?>
                  <option><?php echo $row1[1]; ?></option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </select>
                <button class="Submit" ><span><strong>Search<strong></span></button>
                <!--<input class="Submit" type="submit" name="search" value="Search </span>">-->
            </div>
            <div id="Data_Grid" class="Data_Grid">
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Server ID</th>
                      <th>Client</th>
                      <th>Operator</th>
                      <th>Username</th>
                      <th>Password</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($SearchResult)):; ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $row['ServerID']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['Brand_Name']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['Operator_Name']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['Username']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['Password']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                  </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Footer" class="Footer">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what did you try to make the filter work? You've tagged the question with JavaScript but don't actually show any JavaScript code.

Comment: You can use the onChange() function to get the value from the <select>. After you have done this you can apply that value in a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML code, your `select` element has no `name` attribute, so you won't be able to pick up its value when the form is submitted. Additionally, your `option` elements have no `value` attribute so even if the form was submitted and the `select` had a name, the value would be empty. [See this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp).

Your `select` element isn't inside a `form` tag, which means that the page has no idea where to go when the button is pressed. You need a form that specifies the action (the URL you are going to) and the method (post/get). [See this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

Finally, if you want PHP to know what your query was, you need to get it from the [GET or POST parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php). Once you have the variable, you can make your SQL query dynamic - but be careful *not* to introduce an [SQL injection vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) - validate the user input carefully (for instance, only allowing numbers as values in your select list) and/or use parameterized queries.

If you want the form to be submitted automatically when the dropdown list is changed, you can [use a quick JS attribute to auto-submit the form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7231215/534406).

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the filter value to your query, for your example
you need to construct a new query depending on your selection.

"SELECT * FROM Brands WHERE Client=" + $selectedClient;

Edit:
Here's a reference on how to pass a js variable to php:
[How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)