# How to send an image to server automatically?

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I want the user to upload an image to the server without hitting the submit button.

This is my html form:

```
<form>
    <div class="entry">Upload image<input type="file" formmethod="post" formaction="/avatar_upload"/></div>
</form>
```

Is it possible to upload the file to the server without using the submit button?

Comment: So the question is how to submit a file upload without pressing a submit button?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: So then, this is not about MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use onchange event of the input button to fire the save.

Comment: Sorry to ask you, but how exactly should I use it? I suppose I have to make post  request in this situation?

Comment: Sample code in this fiddle <https://jsfiddle.net/shubmittal/qhecy6fp/1/>

Comment: You can also find examples in this stackoverflow discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231157/how-to-submit-form-on-change-of-dropdown-list

Answer (score 0):

Change your markup like this (add id attributes):

```
<form id="form">
    <div class="entry">Upload image
        <input id="file" type="file" formmethod="post" formaction="/avatar_upload"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

In Javascript (assuming jQuery is used):

```
$('#file').on('change', function () {
    $('#form').submit();
});
```