# django: update field after drop down selection without javascript

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a data table as a formset with several columns. One of the columns is a drop down field. I want to update the value of a field depending on the selected value of the drop down field and I would prefer a solution without using javascript.

Is this possible in django?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I should have searched for something like "[using href links inside option tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2000689/10417877)" or "[How to submit form on change of dropdown list?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7231215/10417877)". Yes, both solutions make use of javascript but this is as much javascript as I can take :-)