# Get value from dropdown list without having to click button

Tags: html

I need to know how can I get value from dropdown list after I selected it. But I don't need to click the button before pass the value.

Comment: Could you please add minimal code on what you are having or what you have tried as of now?

Comment: There is an event in javascript called onChange ,it will trigger just when new value is selected,Thus you can get value of selected field by creating a function using event argument

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use Javascript to submit the form after selecting an option.

I can't vouch for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231157/how-to-submit-form-on-change-of-dropdown-list) but I filed it for future use if I ever wanted to do that. It's beautifully concise.